# seaborn 0.13.0 pointplot native_scale TypeError: pointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'native_scale'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scale, pointplot

According to the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) seaborn pointplot says:

> By default, this function treats one of the variables as categorical and draws data at ordinal positions (0, 1, … n) on the relevant axis. As of version 0.13.0, this can be disabled by setting native_scale=True.

it goes on to say native_scale is :

> "new in version 0.13.0

I have seaborn version 0.13.0, but it throws unexpected keyword error when I pass `native_scale`. Here is a MWE in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import seaborn as sns 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

!pip3 show seaborn
```

returns:

> Name: seaborn
> Version: 0.13.0
> Summary: Statistical data visualization
> Home-page:
> Author:
> Author-email: Michael Waskom mwaskom@gmail.com
> License:
> Location: //site-packages
> Requires: matplotlib, numpy, pandas

```
datax = [ 10**i for i in range(5)]
datay = [ i for i in range(5)]
sns.pointplot(x = datax, y = datay, native_scale = True)
plt.show()
```

line starting with `sns...`returns error:

> TypeError: pointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'native_scale'

Comment: I'd guess you didn't update the correct environment. Do `print(sns.__version__)`

Comment: The code works for me using v0.13. I think you forgot to reload the module

Comment: IIRC, `!pip` inside jupyter notebook only runs in the base environment, not the notebook environment.

Comment: `print(sns.__version__)` shows it is an older version. I made the same script and ran from terminal, and it worked as expected. So this is a separate question of "How do I make sure my notebook environment matches my base environment?"